# Is there anyway to clear a textarea without using an onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve an automatic clear and display another value corresponds to new inputted data

This is my html code for input data and text area

```js
function getInputValue(){
   
    var integer = document.getElementById("integer").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("answer");
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= integer; i++) {
        if (i % 15 == 0){
          text.append( i, "= ","fizzbuzz\n")
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0){
            text.append( i, "= ","fizz \n")
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0){
            text.append( i, "= ","buzz \n")
        }
        else{
          text.append(i, "= \n")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            
  <input class="form-control" id="integer" onChange="getInputValue()" type="text" placeholder="Input an Integer for N" data-sb-validations="required" />
  <label for="integer">Input an Integer for N</label>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 form-floating answer mb-3">
     <textarea disabled class="form-control" id="answer" type="text" placeholder="Answer" style="height: 20rem"></textarea>
 </div>
```

If you will try to run the snippet you can see that if you will change the value in the input tag the textarea will just stack all the outputs

Comment: can't you do it on `Enter` key event? just an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `append()` always it is always adding to content. Just clear it everytime `onChange` is triggered so it resets. You can use :
`text.innerHTML = '';`

```js
function getInputValue(){
   
    var integer = document.getElementById("integer").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("answer");
    text.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= integer; i++) {
        if (i % 15 == 0){
          msg = i + "fizzbuzz";
          text.append( i, "= ","fizzbuzz\n")
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0){
            text.append( i, "= ","fizz \n")
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0){
            text.append( i, "= ","buzz \n")
        }
        else{
          text.append(i, "= \n")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            
  <input class="form-control" id="integer" onChange="getInputValue()" type="text" placeholder="Input an Integer for N" data-sb-validations="required" />
  <label for="integer">Input an Integer for N</label>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 form-floating answer mb-3">
     <textarea disabled class="form-control" id="answer" type="text" placeholder="Answer" style="height: 20rem"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
let inputEl = document.querySelector('#integer')
let answerEl = document.querySelector('#answer')
inputEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
  answerEl.value = ''
  if (inputEl.value !== '') {
    answerEl.value = getInputValue()
  }
})

function getInputValue() {
  var integer = inputEl.value;
  var text = '';

  for (var i = 1; i <= integer; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0) {
      text += i +"= fizzbuzz\n"
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
      text += i +" = fizz \n"
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
      text += i +" = buzz \n"
    } else {
      text += i +" = \n"
    }
  }

  return text
}
```

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3">

  <input class="form-control" id="integer" type="text" placeholder="Input an Integer for N" data-sb-validations="required" />
  <label for="integer">Input an Integer for N</label>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 form-floating answer mb-3">
  <textarea disabled class="form-control" id="answer" type="text" placeholder="Answer" style="height: 20rem"></textarea>
</div>
```

For context.

1. Remove the inline `onChange="getInputValue()"`
2. Setup getInputValue as a return type
3. Check if input is empty else run function

Answer (score -1):

**As far as I can see here, there isn't a way to clear a textarea without using an onclick function.**

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you I will just have to make a button with an onclick function for the clear part

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `oninput` event instead of the `onchange` event.